# iosのaction名はなぜdidSelectとchangedなのですか？

Tags: ios

selectedやdidChangeではないのはなぜでしょうか

Comment: action名とは何を指しますでしょうか？delegate method のことであれば、selectedやdidChangeもありますよ！ `didChange(_:valuesAt:forKey:)` とか

Comment: ありがとうございます。私が見たアクション名は、UIButtonやUITextFieldやUITableViewのaction名でした。もし、Appleがその辺適当で、混在しているだけなのでアレばそう回答くださると嬉しいです。